# How to configure Prometheus to scrape new CE on GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

I am trying to configure a Prometheus instance on a compute engine on GCP to scrape metrics from several compute engine instances. About that, everything should be standard but how should I configure Prometheus to individuate automatically new Compute Engines instances?
For the moment I am not using K8s.

For instance:
I have 2 nginx instances monitored with Prometheus. If I add a new nginx instance I would like to have new metrics on Prometheus automatically.

Thanks

Comment: It is often a part of an environment pipeline, where the process of the monitoring onboarding is automated within and during the onboarding. Alternatively native service discovery configuration: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#gce_sd_config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this will solves your problem.

I have node exporter installed on all my instances and the automatic discovery service configured for it. On top of that, a few instances have their own app_exporter that publishes app specific metrics on another port (9854).

What I did:
I added an extra GCP discovery scraper job for that port:

```
  scrape_configs:
    # Dynamic GCP service discovery for extra app-metrics
    - job_name: 'gcp_solr_discovery'
      metrics_path: "/admin/metrics"
      gce_sd_configs:
         # Europe West 1
       - project: "your-project-here"
         zone: "europe-west1-b"
         port: 9854
       - project: "your-project-here"
         zone: "europe-west1-c"
         port: 9854
```

This will make the GCP service discovery query those ports regardless if the  VMs have node exporter or not and your instances will be added dynamically.

Comment: How about the VM IP address? Does the above config will result in scraping all the VMs in that project space and in that region?

Comment: It will scrape the zone. To scrape the whole region add "zone_filter: us-central1-*" instead of "zone: "europe-west1-c""

Comment: @TudorIftimie where is `zone_filter` documented? Can't find anything like that in the docs

Comment: @SantaXL . https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/list is this what you are looking for ? (see filter section)